# How to create "add to favorites" functional using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just can’t find any information about the implementation of the system of adding to favorites for registered users.

The model has a Post model. It has a couple of fields of format `String`. The `author` field, which indicates which user made the `POST` request, etc.

But how to make it so that the user can add this Post to his “favorites”, so that later you can get a `JSON` response with all the posts that he added to himself. Well, respectively, so that you can remove from favorites.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `favorite_posts` field (many-to-many) in your `Author` model.

Comment: Please consider adding an example and more elaborating on how to use it. This is not very help full.